# List(Of...) WebBrowser - How to declare Web Browsers based on number of strings in an array

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to grab images from a number of similar URLs (The urls do not end in an image format like .jpg). The number of URLs can vary, and is determined by counting the number of strings in an array of strings.

The best method I have found for downloading images from a website is taken from here:
https://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/how-to-use-visual-studio-2012-to-download-images-from-websites.htm

This was working perfectly, however now I need to be able to declare more web browsers, depending on how many urls have to be visited to grab images for downloading. The following is what I would like to be able to do:

```
Dim photonumbers() As String = {"hdshshaga","sjshaghah","akajaha"} 
Dim WebBrowsers As New List(Of WebBrowser)
Dim x As Integer

For x = 0 To photonumbers.Count - 1 Step 1        
    WebBrowsers.Add("wb"&x.ToString) 'I understand I am trying to add a string to a list of webbrowsers, but is there a way to declare a new webbrowser with this name?
Next
```

The reason I want to declare a new webbrowser for each url is that I cannot get the code from the above link to work as a single function solution. Instead you have to download the URL onto the web browser using one subroutine (eg.Triggered by a Button click), and then save all images from that webbrowser with the next subroutine. If anyone is able to advise me on how to change this code to a single function so that it can be called for each string, that would be even better.

Comment: You could just say `New WebBrowser() With {.Name = "wb"&x.ToString}` although i'm not sure why you'd need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim photonumbers() As String = {"hdshshaga", "sjshaghah", "akajaha"}
    Dim WebBrowsers As New List(Of WebBrowser)

    For Each photonumber As String In photonumbers
        WebBrowsers.Add(New WebBrowser() With {.Name = "wb" & photonumber})
    Next
```